# memory leak with symfony2 & swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using a symfony2 command as a cron job to send bulk email to members of a site.

Actual Code:

```
$output->writeln('Before: '.(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024));

$mailer->send($m);

$output->writeln('After: '.(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024));
```

My results:

```
Before: 182.38 MB
After: 183.73 MB
```

Every time I send an email, swiftmailer is consuming an additional 1+MB of memory. That just doesn't seem right, but the memory increases every single time a new message is sent. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: +1 for putting something interesting on the table

Comment: We'll need to see more code and details about the email. Are you attaching files? Are you clearing/resetting things properly between emails?

Comment: It seems to be a well-known bug with no well-known solution. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swiftmailer/y2g3vFd_mPk) and [here](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/88)

Comment: no attachments, i'm initiating a new Swift_Message object in between each send as the emails are entirely custom for each user, but there is no significant amount of memory loss in the creation of new message objects, it's specifically the act of using the send() function. i've also disabled the throttler, and even the final mail() call itself without success. it seems like it's relative to an object not being unset, but still searching through the code

Comment: I've found that if I comment out the event dispatcher codes in the transport's send() function that the memory leak disappears. so it's definitely an issue with the events stuff.. probably will just create my own throttling method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Not sure why users are downvoting. The fact is that swiftmailer itself has a memory leak directly related to its events/plugin system. When hooks are executed it eats away memory which never gets released. Solely removing the events system alone fixed the memory leak without breaking the way swiftmailer works when it comes to actually sending email.

I fixed the problem. I edited the MailTransport class and removed the events system in swiftmailer. I am only allowing the message itself to be built and sent, none of the before and after plugin crap.

I took the pieces from the throttlerplugin and created by own version of it which specifically will only handle messages per minute:

```
class EmailThrottler {

    private $startTime;
    private $messagesPerMinute;
    private $_messages;

    public function __construct($messagesPerMinute = 25)
    {
        $this->startTime = time();
        $this->messagesPerMinute = $messagesPerMinute;
        $this->_messages = 0;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->_messages++;
        $duration = time() - $this->startTime;
        $sleep = $this->_throttleMessagesPerMinute($duration);

        if ($sleep > 0) {
            sleep($sleep);
        }
    }

    private function _throttleMessagesPerMinute($duration)
    {
        $expectedDuration = $this->_messages / ($this->messagesPerMinute / 60);
        return (int) ceil($expectedDuration - $duration);
    }

}
```

I initialized my custom throttler class before the mailing loop:

```
$throttler = new EmailThrottler($pendingCampaign->getRateLimit());
```

and I run it after every sent email:

```
$mailer->send($m);
$throttler->run();
```

Hopefully they find a fix to their events system. I am going to see if the performance is any different on 5.4 anyway, but to those who are on 5.3 this solution I just detailed worked for me on 5.3

Cheers :)

Comment: It seems that this problem still actual.

Answer (score 5):

### SwiftMailer memory spooling system

The problem you're pointing is actually more a solution than a problem. You're not doing anything wrong, and it's due to SwiftMailer's internal way of spooling sent emails.

Upon `send()` method, SwiftMailer doesn't actually send anything, instead simply place it into his spool. By default, the spooling option is `memory`, and spool flush happens right before the Kernel terminates. So there is no chance that `memory_get_usage()` will tell you that memory has been released (because obviously, your script is still running and SwiftMailer hasn't flushed its spool yet).

From Symfony2 documentation:

> When you use spooling to store the emails to memory, they will get
>   sent right before the kernel terminates. This means the email only
>   gets sent if the whole request got executed without any unhandled
>   Exception or any errors.

### Using file spooling system

If this spooling option causes you trouble, you can switch to the `File` spooling option.

It can be done by changing this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
swiftmailer:
    # ...
    spool: { type: memory }
```

To this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
swiftmailer:
    # ...
    spool:
        type: file
        path: /path/to/spool
```

Then, you can configure a cron job to automatically and periodically flush the spool:

```
$ php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod
```

### Using no spool

Or, you can choose to use no spool system at all, which means that all you email will be sent during the execution of your script. It will get you rid of memory problems, but may potentially hurt your users depending on if you're sending mail while they're requesting a page. But as you're doing this by cron job, in your case it certainly won't be a problem. Could be one day, though.

Comment: this would be the case if i'm spooling, but i'm not spooling. the messages are going out immediately via the mail() command, except when throttled via the throttler plugin. the throttler plugin according to documentation only uses the sleep() command though to pause between messages. I've found that if I comment out the event dispatcher codes in the transport's send() function that the memory leak disappears. so it's definitely an issue with the events stuff.. probably will just create my own throttling method

Comment: ok, I thought you were spooling because it's the default configuration.

Comment: appreciate your input anyway, i'm sure your answer will help lots of others with that problem though. thank you much

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I've been struggling for days to find out why emails wouldn't send from my beanstalkd worker daemon. 

Now it makes sense now I know that Symfony won't actually send the spool until the Symfony kernel terminates. As I had a Symfony command running as a daemon, the kernel would never terminate!

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar memory problem sending emails with swiftmailer. It seems that the plugins create these memory leaks, so is not necessary to remove the event dispatcher code, simply disable the plugins (and as for your case, patch with your own solution).

Using simfony2, disable logging is easy, in the config:

```
swiftmailer:
    logging: false
```

or with multiple mailers:

```
swiftmailer:
    mailers:
        my_mailer:
            logging: false
```

In my case, sending ~1500 emails, the memory was growing up to ~100MB (just because of the logger), now >0.2MB .

I know it's a little bit late, but maybe this can be useful to someone that get into the same problem. :-)

Comment: Ahh true, I would have gone with this solution if it had been proposed sooner.